# How to count records in sql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I know how to get the number of rows using mysql_num_rows.
What i want to do is count each ip address, so i can count how many diffrent ip addresses are in my db.
if that makes sense lol.
cause there is just over 1,000 records.
so let me show you a quick example.

say i have these ip addresses.

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.2
127.0.0.3
127.0.0.3
```

i want it to count 1 of each. and print 3 or whatever ammount i have in my database not count all which is what mysql_num_rows does and prints 7.

sorry if the title isn't very specific.

Comment: Based on the selected answer... maybe the title would more appropriately read:  "How to get distinct rows from sql database (so that I can return all of the rows to the client, and count the rows on the client to get a count)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the MySQL [Distinct Clause](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)

```
SELECT DISTINCT IpAddress FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Good luck  @КристинаСоколова :)

Comment: Still worked fine, and he was indeed the first to respond judging by the time of posting :) I know it may not be "good practice" but it still works for my project so i've upvoted it :D

Comment: @КристинаСоколова  Let us know how "brilliantly" this approach to getting a count works out for you performance and scalability-wise when you've got  375,000 distinct values for `IpAddress` to return.

Comment: @spencer7593 It was an honest mistake. Here, I fixed it.

Comment: @spencer7593 No reason to get angry bud, we're all here to help each other/ask for help. Don't be so rude. His example even with the brackets still worked fine for me. and my website will never get 375,000 views.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `distinct` and `count` features together:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct ip_address) FROM some_table;
```

Comment: Your answer was aswell great :D

Answer (score 2):

Use `DISTINCT` to count once. Not involving the duplicates. Try this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT IP) 
FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ip , COUNT(ip)
FROM table_name GROUP BY ip
```